# when using paper.js importSVG(), how to change its path?

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

With Paper.js, I've imported an SVG using:

```
var kanji = project.importSVG(url, {
  expandShapes: true,
  onLoad: function(item) {
    console.log("imported SVG!");

  },
  onError: console.log("something went wrong importing")
});
```

This successfully adds the svg to my canvas. However, I want to manipulate the SVG's path. When the code reaches the onLoad scope I get confused. Here I get the svg that I named `item` , which is a big and complex object:

```
initialize {_children: Array(3), _namedChildren: {…}, _matrix: t, _id: 1, _index: 0, …}
```

With the content of the children array having even more children an lots of other options. 
I want to access/copy/manipulate the nodes of the path, but I can't even find the path in the object. How can I do this?
Seems easier to just get the path from the svg file itself. Or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you import SVG into `Paper.js`, a wrapper group is created representing the root `<svg>` tag.
You can navigate the `Paper.js` items tree like you would do with a common `DOM` tree using items `children` (for groups only) and `parent` properties.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating the solution.

```
// This represents the source svg.
const svg = '' +
    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="267px" height="277px" viewBox="0 0 267 277">' +
    '    <g>' +
    '        <polygon fill="#FFED00" points="180,183 26,183 26,29 181,28 "/>' +
    '        <path fill="#009FE3" d="M243,183c0-34.794-28.206-64-63-64s-63,29.206-63,64s28.206,63,63,63S243,217.794,243,183z"/>' +
    '    </g>' +
    '</svg>';

// We import the svg.
// What we get in return is a wrapper group corresponding to the `<svg>` tag.
const svgGroup = project.importSVG(svg);
// Then we can get our group (`<g>` tag) by accessing the last child of the svg group (the first child is a clip mask corresponding to the `<svg>` `viewBox` attribute).
const group = svgGroup.lastChild;
// Then we can get our path...
const path = group.lastChild;
// ...and do what we want with it.
path.firstSegment.point += 20;
```

Comment: that's a good example! However my `group.lastChild` returns _null_ . Does that mean that the file isn't loaded into canvas yet or something?

Comment: Interestingly enough your code works differently in my script. I can only replicate it with 
`var path = svgGroup._children[1].lastChild;` 
`path.firstSegment.point += 20;`

For my SVG it's a bit of an awkward code to turn it into a path and change its segments but at least it works:
`var myPath = new Path(
item.children[1].lastChild.children[1].children[1].children[1]._segments
);` I'll mark this question answered, and will figure out why my case is different elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: where | how do we import this `project`. I am getting an error that its null.

Comment: It's because my code is written in PaperScript (with paper.js being added to the window object), you should be able to do `paper.project` instead.